# ggvis: Transforming numeric values in the dataset using a slider

Tags: r, input, slider, ggvis

I am trying to use `input_slider(1,10)` to transform the values in my dataset by multiplying them by a selected value. For example, if the the selected value is 2, I would like the values to become 120*2, 140*2, 100*2.

Here is my example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(year=c(1,2,3), value=c(120,140,100))
mydata %>%
  ggvis(~year, ~value) %>%
  layer_bars()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `input_slider` for `y`, using the `map` argument to multiply the slider results with your `value` variable.

```
mydata %>%
    ggvis(~year, y = input_slider(1, 10, value = 1, label = "Multiplier", 
                                    map = function(x) x*.$value)) %>% 
    layer_points()
```

However, this doesn't actually work with `layer_bars` at the moment.

You can get around this by working with `layer_rects`, but then you have to put in the bar width, which all works out better if `year` is a factor.

```
 mydata %>%
    ggvis(~factor(year), y = input_slider(1, 10, value = 1, label = "Multiplier", 
                                 map = function(x) x*.$value)) %>% 
    layer_rects(y2 = 0, width = band())
```

I did find one other alternative after finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102711/2461552).  In your case, you could use `mutate` to essentially recalculate your y variable and then use that in `layer_bars`.  Note the use of `eval`.  You can see some more examples of this approach on the help page for `dplyr-ggvis` (`?"dplyr-ggvis"`).

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
    ggvis(~year, ~value) %>%
    mutate(value = eval(input_slider(1, 10, value = 1, label = "Multiplier"))*value) %>%
    layer_bars()
```